# When is the word "frequent" used and when should it be "frequently"?

Tags: grammar

We investigated disease activity in female and male patients. Our results suggest that females had higher disease activity than males. So I would like to say that they had less frequent or frequently low disease activity.

I have a sentence I would like to write, which version is correct and why?

1. *Females had less **frequently** low disease activity*
2. *Females had less **frequent** low disease activity*

Comment: You should perhaps include a description of what you intend the sentence to mean, so that people can decide which is correct.

Comment: Well, I meant to say that we investigated disease activity in female and male patients. Our results suggest that females had higher disease activity than males. So I would like to say that they had less frequent or frequently low disease activity.

Comment: What is “higher disease activity”?

Comment: See usage frequency https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=less+frequent%2C+less+frequently&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cless%20frequent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cless%20frequently%3B%2Cc0

Comment: What is "disease activity" (high or low)?

Comment: @Xanne and Weather Vane, disease activity is a term used in medicine to reflect whether a patient has high or low disease activity based on objective parameters such as inflammation markers or patient-reported outcome measures (e.g., patient reports to have pain of 9 on a scale of 0-10).

Comment: So it means symptoms?

Comment: Do you mean a low *occurrence* of disease activity?

Comment: @WeatherVane apologies for all the confusion. I mean that, in my study, female patients had less often low disease activity (female vs. male, 30% vs. 45%). I hope this clarifies things a bit. Here is an example of a disease activity composite score: https://www.asas-group.org/instruments/asdas-calculator/


Basically, if you fill out the parameters and score less than 2.1 on the composite score (in this case called ASDAS), you have low disease activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Frequent* is an adjective, *frequently* an adverb.

> We have had frequent showers of rain this week.
>
> It has rained frequently this week.

So if you consider 'low disease activity' as a noun phrase, you describe it as *frequent,* but if you want to say that females had it less often, they had it less *frequently.*

Comment: Is it worth also mentioning word order here? As in, typically an adverb wouldn't go in between the verb and the object ("I frequently eat fish" or "I eat fish frequently", but not "\*I eat frequently fish").